# key pressed down not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

I have text box where I want to send data (*myButton*) when I press Return.

```
private void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        // Shift + Return
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        // Return
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text))
            myButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

This works fine if I have some text but when I don't have text, if I press Return it adds a new line and I don't want that. Any sugestion?

Comment: You have to set `e.Handled` to `true` to stop the event propagating.

Comment: Set multiline to false?

Comment: @KingKing sorry, I meant `txtBox`

Comment: if the textbox doesnt have any text, then the condition !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace will evaluate to false

Comment: per @KarelFrajtak It's likely adding a newline whether the button event is fired or not...

Comment: @NithinNayagam yes, that's what the OP **intends**, no problem with that. just add an `else` to the `if-statement` and set `e.Handled = true`.

Comment: @KingKing `e.Handled = true` didn't work :/

Comment: This `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text)) sendButton.PerformClick(); else e.Handled = true;` solved the newline issue but it's sending empty strings

Comment: and if I enter some text _myButton_ is not performed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want lines to be added to the TextBox then you should set its Multiline property to False.

Generally, if you don't want the Enter key to be processed then you'll need to prevent the KeyPress event for it from firing.  Which you do by setting the e.SuppressKeyPress property to true.  Fix:

```
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
{
    // Return
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text))
        myButton.PerformClick();
    e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I just wanted to add lines when Shift + Return is pressed.